# Tapkey Mobile SDK missing build when using Objective C for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, tapkey

I get this error message when trying to use the Tapkey Mobile SDK for iOS in a Objective C AppDelegate:

> No visible @interface for 'TKMServiceFactoryBuilder' declares the selector 'build'

This is the code I use to initialize the ServiceFactory:

`TKMServiceFactoryBuilder *builder = [[TKMServiceFactoryBuilder alloc] init]; self.tapkeyServiceFactory = [builder build];`

Here is the error message as screenshot:

[image]

Am I missing some imports? The code above with the config has a valid build method. I can also use the `setConfig` to use the config above.

Or am I just not using the library correctly in Objetcive C?

The project is React Native. The SDK is working with Android using the React Native Bridge and I want to add it to iOS to.

The SDK is prepared for iOS but unfortunately the AppDelegate is in objetcive c and not swift. There is no documentation on how to use it with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tapkey Mobile SDK for iOS` does not support objc:
https://developers.tapkey.io/mobile/ios/getting_started/#requirements

Comment: So I would need to convert my Objective C AppDelegate to one written in swift?

Comment: Either that or adding an wrapper for the initialisation part, if it not possible to convert the AppDelegate to objc itself.

Anyway, the most of the services and types are plain swift and won't be accessible through objc. For these adapters would have to be implemented.

The reason is that the SDK uses a lot of async code (promises etc.) which rely on generic types. Generic types are not supported by objc in that way. Additional not all native swift types are available via in objc.